# Extracting Contacts from android and saving to the database

Tags: java, php, android, arrays

So far I have been able to extract contacts both number and name, What I want to do is to send the data to the database via php. So far so good, instead It is sending only the last one in the array, Any suggestions as to how i can send the array and save the whole extracted contacts?

Java

```
 String URL ="http://192.168.0.10/oap/home/SynchContacts/";

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String name,email;
            name = Name.getText().toString();
            email = Email.getText().toString();

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    builder.setTitle("Server Title");
                    builder.setMessage(response);
                    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog bu = builder.create();
                    bu.show();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver(); //Activity/Application android.content.Context
                    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
                    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
                    {
                        alContacts = new ArrayList<String>();
                        do
                        {
                            String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                            if(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
                            {
                                Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",new String[]{ id }, null);
                                while (pCur.moveToNext())
                                {
                                    String contactNumber = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                                   // alContacts.add('{'+name+":"+contactNumber);

                                   param = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                    param.put("name[]", name);
                                     param.put("phone[]", contactNumber);
                                    break;
                                }
                                pCur.close();
                            }

                        } while (cursor.moveToNext()) ;

                    }

                    return param;

                }
            };
            MySingleton.getInstance(MainActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

        }
    });
```

PHP

```
function SynchContacts() {

        $phone= $this->input->post('phone');
       $name= $this->input->post('name');

       for ($i=0; $i<count($phone);$i++){
           $data = array(
               'name'=>$name[$i],
               'phone'=>$phone[$i]
           );
           $this->saveData('phonebook', $data);
       }

    }
```

Comment: Well, you keep overwriting your values in your `HashMap`, which does not look right.

Comment: Assistance on rewriting the place where i keep rewriting @CommonsWare?